# How to change color of dynamically loaded active button/tab onPress in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a list of category from calling external API and I am displaying it in a flatlist like this in horizontal scroll
[image]

but it is not changing state onPress , I want it should change color when user click on particular tab/button

my API json format data is like this

```js
    const data = [
        {
            id: '1',
            title: 'General'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Student-Visa'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Study'
        },
        {
            id: '4',
            title: 'Festival'
        },
        {
            id: '5',
            title: 'NorthIndian-Food'
        },
    ]
```

and I am using it as

```js
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
        <View key={index} style={selectedCategory === item.title ? styles.activeCategory : styles.categoryContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.6}
                underlayColor={COLORS.white}
                onPress={()=>handleCategory(item.title)}
            >
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
    return (
        <List
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            horizontal={true}
            style={styles.container}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
    )
```

```js
    const handleSelectedCategory = (title) => {
        setSelectedCategory(title);
        console.log(selectedCategory);
    }
    
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState();
```

I am using it as a separate component in another component

```
<FAQcategory selectedCategory={selectedCategory} />
```

any suggestion ? or help what I am doing wrong
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(0); // should be item index

const handleCategory = (index) => {
  setSelectedCategory(index);
};

const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <View
    key={index}
    style={
      selectedCategory === index
        ? styles.activeCategory
        : styles.categoryContainer
    }
  >
    <TouchableOpacity
      ....
      onPress={() => handleCategory(index)} // send index in param
    > 
       ....
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```